# How to make the radio button for entities

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tables such as

in User.php

```
  /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\IconPics", inversedBy="icon")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 */
private $icon;
```

in Icon.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="icon")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $icon;
```

icon table is like

```
|id |icon
|1  |aaa.png
|2  |bbb.png
|3  |ccc.png
```

I want to make the user choose one icon via form.

```
$builder->add('icon',null,array('label' => 'select icon'));
```

it shows  pull down on HTML and user can select one of aaa~ccc.jpg

but I want to use radio button for this.

```
$builder->add('icon','choice',array('label' => 'select icon'));

$builder->add('icon','radio',array('label' => 'select icon'));
```

I have tried these but they don't show candidates.

How can I make radio button to select items in database icon.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select **one** of your icon entities using radio buttons you are looking for the [Entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) with the [`expanded`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) attribute set to `true` and [`multiple`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) set to `false`.

```
$builder->add('icon', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeUserBundle:IconPic',
    'property' => 'image', // .. or whatever property the image location is stored.
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
));
```